# Twitter Trends PHP

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I am trying to use http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?exclude=hashtags however I am having some trouble.

So, I'm trying to use:

```
  <?php
$init = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?exclude=hashtags';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$init);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);


foreach ($obj[0]['trends'] as $trend) {
    print $trend['query'];
    echo "<br>";
    print $trend['name'];
    echo "<hr>";
}

?>
```

And I am getting this Error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in \index.php on line 11

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() \index.php on line 11

Answer (score 2):

You read the JSON wrong. You need to do something like the following:

```
foreach ($obj['trends']['2011-02-23 18:00:00'] as $trend) {
    print $trend['query'];
    echo "<br>";
    print $trend['name'];
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong

```
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
```

would produce an array and not an object. secondly using the twitter api is as simple as:

```
<?php
function get_trends($woeid){
    return json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/".$woeid.".json?exclude=hashtags", true), false); 
}
$data = get_trends(23424848); //23424848 is woeid for India...
$trends = $data[0]->trends;
echo "<ul>";
if(!empty($trends)){
    foreach($trends as $trend){
        echo '<li><a href="'.$trend->url.'" target="_blank">'.$trend->name.'</a></li>';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```